# Ошибка mixed content при запросе с https на http

Tags: nginx, ssl, https

Сервер на nginx
На нем два приложения: клиент и сервер
Клиент привязан с домену (domain.ru), а сервер просто крутится на 5000 порту (domain.ru:5000)
Приобрел ssl сертификат, настроил его только на клиент, теперь клиент на https, а сервер так и остался на http

Когда отправляются запросы на сервер, то падает ошибка:
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://domain.ru/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://domain.ru:5000/...'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Можно ли как-то прикрутить ssl именно к порту?
Можно ли вообще использовать 1 ssl на 2 приложения?
Или придется покупать отдельный домен/поддомен для серверного приложения?

nginx конфиг

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name domain.ru www.domain.ru;
  return 301 https://domain.ru;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

  server_name domain.ru www.domain.ru;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/domain.ru/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/domain.ru/privkey.pem;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

Comment: можно. можно. не прийдётся

Comment: Что мешает запихнуть использование этого порта в тот же самый nginx?